# MVP in WinForms ( presenter & program.cs)

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I'm learning an MVP pattern and have the following issues:

If I have one form(project MainForm), one model(project Model) and one presenter, should I create a new project for my presenter or it's ok to put it in MainForm project?

1)If presenter must be located in separate project, it obviously needs a reference to MainForm for it's constructor, what leads us to the second problem:

When the app starts in program.cs (which is in MainForm) I need to create my presenter:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Presenter presenter = new Presenter(new MainForm()); //Here it is
        Presenter.Run();
    }
```

But, since presenter is in a separate project, I can not use it without a reference. However, there is already a reference from presenter to MainForm so i can't add it.

2)If presenter is located in MainForm project, the program starts fine, but to use functions from Model I have to add a reference from MainForm project to Model project, which, I think, contradicts MVP pattern.

Please, tell me how to design my sulution properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your View and Model should be independent of each other and the Presenter. They *may* live in their own projects, but it would be fine in a simple program for everything to be in the same project.

If you do want them in separate projects, that is easily done. The main project, containing the `Program` class, will also contain the *`Presenter`* class. The View (i.e. the `MainForm` class) and the Model would (could) then be in their own projects.

The hierarchy of projects would look something like this:

- Main program EXE project: contains `Presenter` class and `Program` class (i.e. the latter for the program entry point, `Main()` as you show in your code example). References include:

  - View DLL project: contains `MainForm` class (and any other view classes)
  - Model DLL project: contains model class(es)

In other words, you can create a Windows Forms project for the main program project, and just delete the default `Form1` that's created there for you. You can create a class library project for the view DLL project and add a Windows Form class to that project for your `MainForm` class.